# What is the meaning of "I do believe it. That's what I don't believe."?

Tags: meaning

Peter telling about his life to Regina:

> Peter: Well, in this highly competitive world when a man has no
>   profession, there isn't  much choice so I began looking for people who
>   had more money than they needed including some they'd barely miss.
>
> Regina: You mean you're a thief?
>
> Peter: Well, that's not exactly the term I'd have chosen but it sort
>   of captures the spirit of the thing.
>
> Regina: I don't believe it.
>
> Peter: I can't really blame you now.
>
> Regina: But **I do believe it. That's what I don't believe**.

Comment: The first sentence is a statement of fact that she believes him. The second sentence states that it is this fact she cannot believe.

Comment: She could have just said "I can't believe I believe it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression *I don’t believe X* (or *I can’t believe X*) doesn't always mean that you literally do not believe *X*: more often it expresses surprise or shock or dismay at discovering that *X* is true.

In this case, Peter has just told Regina that he is a professional thief. Regina reacts by saying "I don't believe it", and then clarifies that statement by drawing precisely the distinction I describe above: she **does ‘believe’** what he has said in the sense that she accepts it as a fact but **doesn’t ‘believe’** it in the sense that she is dismayed by the fact.